# Unable to click on a link using repeater in Mac El Capitan Safari browser 9.1 version

Tags: macos, safari, protractor, browserstack

I am doing cross browser testing in browser stack. My protractor tests are passing on all other browsers: Chrome, IE-11, Edge, Firefox but few tests are failing on Safari 9.1 on mac El Capitan. When i used the High Siera and Saffari 11, it will click on the link that was not cliked earlier on safari 9.1 and El Capitan but other tests that were passing on Safari 9.1 and El Capitan were failed. So i am tried with doiing back and forth and unable to make all the test script pass. I am using repeater locator to find the element. Can someone help me to resolve this issue or help me how to deal with this situation.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: can you provide more details? HTML code snippet for the element you are trying to perform the click on, your test script and any stack trace you see when the click fails on Safari 9.1, driver version used for Safari 9.1 ?

Comment: Thank you BountyHunter, by changing the locater to linkText, i solved the problem. Thanks.